# DOMDocument loses some code near php opening tag

Tags: php, encoding, domdocument

I like code element to keep the whole node value. But it loses the part that is: `'<?php $this->'`. Probably it gets that part as html tag. I do not know.
See the snippet:

```
<?php
$text = '<div><code><?php $this->goal = \'żźćłóąę\';</code></div>';
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($text, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8"));
$codeElements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('code');
foreach($codeElements as $elem)
    var_dump($elem->nodeValue);
```

The result is:

```
`string(24) "goal = 'żźćłóąę';"`
```

but should be

```
string(37) "<?php $this->goal = 'żźćłóąę';"
```

How to achive this?

online: https://3v4l.org/d6DFm

Thank you

## edit

After some comments my question needs some explanation.
This

> <?php $this->goal = 'żźćłóąę';

must not be parsed by php interpreter. This must be displayed as a code presentation. The whole text, whole row must be displayed as string. The opening php tag, the variable and the arrow too.

Comment: that's to be expected. PHP is not valid html. you can NOT load html containing php code blocks and expect it to not get trashed. dom sees `<?php $this->` as a broken/invalid html tag, and nukes it.

Comment: Yea. Will never work. If you want to output the PHP variable, can be done but you can't open a php tag inside a php tag.

Comment: I want it to be seen as string. This is for code presentation. Not to parse the php block.

Comment: I try to explain it ones more: that should be the string of the vlaue `"<?php $this->goal = 'żźćłóąę';"` Literally. The php opening tag must be seen on the web page on internet. This opening php tag must not be parsed.

Comment: then embed it into the html as `&lt;?php ... ?&gt;`. that'll pass through DOM as is.

Comment: Is it posible to use any script or function that would do the conversion `<div><code><?php $this->goal = 'żźćłóąę';</code></div>` to `<div><code>&lt;?php $this-&gt;goal = 'żźćłóąę';</code></div>` automaticly? Cause I have code snippets with normal php tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
    <?php
$text = '<div><code><?php $this->goal = \'żźćłóąę\';</code></div>';
$text = str_replace("<?","&lt;?",$text);
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($text, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8"));
$codeElements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('code');
foreach($codeElements as $elem)
    var_dump($elem->nodeValue);
```

Comment: But my text is '<div><code><?php $this->goal = "żźćłóąę";</code></div>'. I get it from database. I have more such a texts in database. They are articles with samles of php code. They all have normal opening php tags.